# Store matched variables

Tags: pattern-matching, variable-definitions

**Edit:**  I am matching and replacing a particular expression.  At the same time...  I want to store matched variables for later use.  I got it to work with messed up code involving `Block`.  Is there a smarter way to do this?

```
(*Initialize*)
variables = {}; expr = f[x] + g[x] + 3 f[y];

(*now match and replace, and storing the argument into "variables"*)
expr /. f[x_] :> Block[{}, variables = Union[variables, {x}]; fNew[x]]
```

Now if I type:

```
variables
(*output is {x,y}*)
```

I get the desired output.

The empty `{}` inside `Block` makes me feel I'm doing this in a kludgy way...  (feel free to improve any other parts of the code too!)

Comment: And what to do for `f[]` or `f[x,y]` ?

Comment: `f[]` and `f[x,y]` do not match.

Comment: but `f[g[x]]` should match?

Comment: yes `f[g[x]]` that should match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sow` and `Reap`:

```
{result, variables} = Reap[
  expr /. f[x_] :> fNew[Sow@x]
  ]
variables
(* Out: {{x, y}} *)
```

In your original solution you do not need `Block`:

```
variables = {};
expr /. f[x_] :> (variables = Union[variables, {x}]; fNew[x])
```

And `AppendTo` can make your code shorter:

```
variables = {};
expr /. f[x_] :> (AppendTo[variables, x]; fNew[x])
```

When collecting many different values such that it may become a performance issue the `Sow` and `Reap` solution is recommended in the documentation and elsewhere. Compared to your code the alternatives do not delete duplicates, you can do this afterwards with `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: Sow? Reap?  So we're farmers now?!  Nice solution.  I'll wait for more answers/comments before accepting this one

Comment: @QuantumDot For what it's worth I would also use `Sow` and `Reap`, but I would not put `Sow` inside `fNew` as I would not assume that it will evaluate (`fNew` might hold its arguments).  I would use:  `expr /. f[x_] :> (Sow @ x; fNew @ x)`

Answer (score 0):

```
variables = Union@Cases[expr, f[x__] :> x, {0, Infinity}]
(* {x, y} *)
```

Comment: Does this give the replaced `expr` as output?  I should have said that outputting the replaced `expr` is needed, and I also need to store the variables on the side.

Comment: `expr /. f[x_] :> fNew[x]`. I'm not quite sure what's the usefulness of combining both steps (replacement and getting variables) into one, but @Pickett's `Sow` and `Reap` do the job very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

another version

```
Clear@"`*"
variables = {};
expr = f[x] + g[x] + 3 f[y] + f[x + y] f[x];
var[x_] := CompoundExpression[variables = variables~Join~{x}, x]

(* usage *)
expr /. f[x_] :> fNew@var@x
variables

(* out *)
fNew[x] + 3 fNew[y] + fNew[x] fNew[x + y] + g[x]
{x, y, x, x + y}
```